# list indices must be integers or slices, not str error when trying to extract data from json file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract some data from a json file in an s3 bucket, however I get this error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Here's the code:

```
content_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=key)['Body']
json_content = json.load(content_object)
for i in json_content:
        ID = json_content[i]['ID']
        DateTime = json_content[i]['DateTime']
        SourceDevice = json_content[i]['SourceDevice']
        DestinationDevice = json_content[i]['DestinationDevice']
        DataType= json_content[i]['DataType']
        Activity = json_content[i]['Activity']
```

And the json file:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "No.",
        "DateTime": "Time",
        "SourceDevice": "Source",
        "DestinationDevice": "Destination",
        "DataType": "Protocol",
        "Activity": "label"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "DateTime": "SomeTime",
        "SourceDevice": "SomeSource",
        "DestinationDevice": "SomeDestination",
        "DataType": "ARP",
        "Activity": "normal"
    },
```

I've been through a lots of topic with the same problem, but I could not find an answer related to my code.Thank you for your help !

Comment: First things first: what's `i` in `for i in json_content` and are you sure it's possible to index `json_content` with `i` later on?

Comment: `for i in json_content:` => `type(i)` ==> dict ... the rest of your code does not make much sense by that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `for x in some_list` in Python, you get the values in the list as `x` automatically, not an index in the list. So you want to do this instead:

```
for item in json_content:
    ID = item['ID']
    ...
```

If you need the list index in the loop as well, use `enumerate`:

```
for index, value in enumerate(json_content):
    print(index, value['SourceDevice']) # prints "0 Source" and "1 SomeSource"
```

Comment: It returns a dict. Thank you very much for your help, it worked fine with your first answer !

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
for i in json_content
```

with

```
for i in range(len(json_content))
```

You are attemtping to index a list with a json_content list element. Alternatively, you can do

```
ID = i['ID']
```

for getting the dictionary elements.